# Chrome Background-size not accurate?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having an issue with background images not scaling correctly in Chrome. I have included my code below as well a codepen link. You will notice that despite being set to 20% width, the background image does fit in perfectly 5 times. Does any one have a fix or workaround for this?

CSS

```
    #vsb-screen-preview { 
    background-image: url(/screen-builder-screen.png); 
    background-size: 20% 25%; 
    background-position: top left; 
    float: left;   
    width: 454px; 
    height: 316px;}

    .vsb-screen-preview-bg {
    float: left; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1); 
    background-image: url(/pexels-photo-361951.jpeg); 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="vsb-screen-preview-bg">
    <div id="vsb-screen-preview">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWMGrz

Comment: what should your final view look like?

Comment: Your overlay image is square(500x500).. So what I will suggest is to use width/height which equates to a square(eg - #vsb-screen-preview{ width:400px; height:400px}) not a rectangle in case of chrome as chrome renders backgrounds this way only.

Comment: @reenleedr the final view is dynamic as I am modifying the values with java script.

Comment: @Sahil Dhir Unfortunately the background image size needs to be flexible (sometimes square, sometimes rectangle)for my requirements, are you saying this is simply not possible in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is a Chrome bug.  When you set the background size, it only repeats and multiplies in integers and not decimal numbers. So if your value is a float, scale or percentage, it will be wrong in Chrome.

I've just discovered that after 2 hours of trying to figure out why chrome spacing is different.

I haven't found a fix yet apart asking for as many people as possible to report the bug so they fix it.